# Mackie HUI MIDI message that will resend all track information? Pro Tools

Tags: midi, coremidi, midi-interface

I am looking for a MIDI message to send Pro Tools via the HUI MIDI spec that will trigger PT to resend all track information (vol/mute/pan/automation state/track-name).

The HUI spec is not publicly available in it's entirety (though theageman has released some of it). Does anyone know if a MIDI message like this exists? I want to send a message that will trigger pro tools to resend all current track info of the currently selected tracks.

Answer (score 0):

The HUI protocol is only a WYSIWYG display system 
in that it: 
SENDS actions by the user 
GETS display information

YOUR OPTIONS ? 
Unofficial [cockos](http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=101328)

You can get the official HUI documentation Loud Technologies
You get the license from:

http://www.loudtechinc.com/

they do not seem to have email (really?)

Matt Redmon 
c/o Loud Technologies/Mackie 
16220 Wood-Red Road NE 
Woodinville, WA 98072 US 
(800) 898-3211  
(425) 487-4337 
ATTN: HUI Protocol License Inquiry

Answer (score 0):

You could send the "SYSTEM RESET" message to ProTools which should make it resend the current HUI display state but you would need to interpret the replay - which is in the form of display and fader information 
But that may be what you are trying to do ?

You could also try lopping through the "Zone" or "next track" messages to get further info

Good luck - let us know how you get on 
David

Comment: I have tried sending the reset message 0x90, 0x00, 0xFF which the HUI supposedly sends when shutting down. Pro Tools does not react at all.